# D opBinary()() overloading bug?

Tags: operator-overloading, overloading, d, dmd

When I try and overload opBinary on a simple Vector struct, I get a strange and meaningless error:

```d
struct Vector(T)
{
    T x, y;

    Vector opBinary(string op)(Vector!float vector)
    {
        return Vector (
            mixin("x" ~ op ~ "vector.x"),
            mixin("y" ~ op ~ "vector.y")
        );
    }

    Vector opBinary(string op)(Vector!double vector)
    {
        return Vector (
            mixin("x" ~ op ~ "vector.x"),
            mixin("y" ~ op ~ "vector.y")
        );
    }
}

void main()
{
    auto dVec = Vector!double();
    auto fVec = Vector!float();

    auto aVec = dVec + fVec; // Adding this line causes error (see below)
}
```

The error I get is simply: "opBinary(string op)". No line numbers, nothing. Which obviously doesn't give me a whole lot to go on. Is there another way to handle this situation? Is this a known bug?

I'm using DMD 2.057 on Windows 7. Haven't tested on Linux yet.

*[EDIT] cleaned the code up a bit for readability.*

Comment: Unrelated to the actual problem, but inside a template, you can use just the template's name to refer to the current instantiation, so instead of `Vector!T`, you can write `Vector`.

Comment: @FiL why you would want to add an object of type `Vector!double` with an object of type `Vector!float` is beyond me.

Comment: @Arlen, normally I don't. I do want it to work thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full error is:

```
main.d(27): Error: template main.Vector!(double).Vector.opBinary(string op) opBinary(string op) matches more than one template declaration, main.d(5):opBinary(string op) and main.d(13):opBinary(string op)
```

VisualD fails to parse it, causing the error you see. Are you using VisualD?

The code works if you change it to something like:

```d
struct Vector(T)
{
    T x, y;

    Vector opBinary(string op, U)(Vector!U vector) if(is(typeof(mixin("x" ~ op ~ "vector.x")) : T))
    {
        return Vector(
            mixin("x" ~ op ~ "vector.x"),
            mixin("y" ~ op ~ "vector.y")
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Though it really shouldn't be using `Vector!T`. As you pointed out in the comments for the question, `Vector` works just fine, since it's inside the template, and in my experience, you're more likely to run into compiler bugs if you use `Vector!T` instead of `Vector` inside the template.

Comment: That was it, thank you again! Looks like I might start using Mono-D on Windows as well. Probably should anyways because of code completion. Also, using a single opBinary(string op, U) works well without needing the if(is(typeof(...))) qualifier.

Comment: @FiL, it's not required, but it's good practice. It raises compile errors earlier and at the right place, lets you overload based on it, and documents just a little bit.